# Multiple try...except block statement throws yet another error

Tags: python, try-catch

My multiple try...except block is not working and I'm not sure why:

```
from datetime import datetime

class Format_DateTime:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __call__(self, text):
        text = text.replace(".", "-")
        text = text.replace("/", "-")
        text = text.replace(" ", "-")
        try: output = datetime.strptime(text, '%d-%m-%Y')
        except ValueError: output = datetime.strptime(text, '%d-%b-%Y')
        except: output = "Please input date as follows: day mth year, e.g. 07 Mar 2020"
        return output

'''EXAMPLE USAGE:'''
if __name__ == "__main__":
    format_datetime = Format_DateTime()
    print(format_datetime('8 04 20'))
```

The above code is meant to throw my error message but throws *yet another* `ValueError` exception, how do I make it throw my message?

Comment: `except ValueError:
            try:output = datetime.strptime(text, '%d-%b-%Y')
            except: output = "Please input date as follows: day mth year, e.g. 07 Mar 2020"`

Comment: Can you post the full traceback? Is the error from the second conversion attempt? You'd have to put it in another try/except ValueError to catch it.

Comment: When you catch your ValueError exception, you run the ```output = datetime.strptime(text, '%d-%b-%Y')``` statement. As ```text``` does not match the pattern either, a new ```ValueError``` exception is thrown and this one is no more encapsulated in a ```try ... except...``` block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each date conversion attempt needs its own exception handler. Its best to avoid putting try/except code on a single line anyway (it reads better and is easier to step through in a deugger) but for this problem you have to

```
def __call__(self, text):
    text = text.replace(".", "-")
    text = text.replace("/", "-")
    text = text.replace(" ", "-")
    try: 
        output = datetime.strptime(text, '%d-%m-%Y')
    except ValueError: 
        try:
            output = datetime.strptime(text, '%d-%b-%Y')
        except ValueError:
            output = "Please input date as follows: day mth year, e.g. 07 Mar 2020"
    return output
```